# MvvmCross Command Pattern

Tags: mvvmcross

I keep noticing two similar patterns for ICommand properties coming up in examples, specifically as shown in the MvvmCross wiki https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#rio:

```
private ICommand _submitCommand;
public ICommand SubmitCommand
{
    get
    {
         _submitCommand = _submitCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoSubmit);
         return _submitCommand;
    }
}
```

And without the backing store and null-coalescing operator, for example:

```
public ICommand SubmitCommand
{
    get
    {
         return new MvxCommand(DoSubmit);
    }
}
```

Which is preferred and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version simply reduces the number of objects created, since only one instance would exist no matter how many times the command property is accessed.

In most cases, this probably doesn't make that much difference. Most people use code snippets to generate the code, so it's not any additional typing to generate the correct code.

Comment: The first also has to be used if you ever want to disable/enable the command (but quite often you don't)